# How to return an object inside an array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have an assignment for uni and I'm stuck with a question for quite some time.

So, I have to return an object which is called Fruit in the method first (which is the method where I need help with).

(Fruit is defined in another class like this : Fruit(String name, String nickname, int taste).)

The method first is meant to return the fruit with the best taste.

But I keep having the NullPointerException for either taste or fruit. I do understand what the error means but I don't have any idea about how to correct it.
Thanks for those who can help! And sorry about the bad English.

```java
public class Four {
    private Fruit[] fruits;
    Four(Fruit f1, Fruit f2, Fruit f3, Fruit f4) {
        Fruit[] m = new Fruit[4];
        m[0] = f1;
        m[1] = f2;
        m[2] = f3;
        m[3] = f4;
    }

    public Fruit[] getFruit() {
        return fruits;
    }

    public Fruit first() { //THIS FIRST LINE CAN'T CHANGE
        Fruit[] e = new Fruit[4];
        Fruit f = e[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            if (f.taste > e[i].taste) {
                f = e[i];
            }
        }
        return f;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fruit f1 = new Fruit("Apple", "Appie", 5);
        Fruit f2 = new Fruit("Strawberry", "Strawy", 20);
        Fruit f3 = new Fruit("Banana", "Banie", 18);
        Fruit f4 = new Fruit("Orange", "Orangi", 8);
        Four m = new Four(f1, f2, f3, f4);
        System.out.println(m.first());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code

```java
Fruit [] e = new Fruit[4];
Fruit f = e[0];
```

The accessed array index `e[0]` has a `null` value. So `f.taste > e[i].taste` will throw NPE. (any `e[i].` will throw NPE)

### Suggested changes

#### Constructor

`Fruit [] m = new Fruit[4];`.

This has to be changed to `fruits = new Fruit[4];` (and all assignments to `m[]` should be made to `fruits[]`

This will help these constructed values to be accessible to other parts of  same object.

Otherwise, the `fruits` instance variable will be `null` and will not track the state of the object.

#### first method

`Fruit [] e = new Fruit[4];`

After making the necessary changes to constructor,
the above line can be changed to `Fruit [] e = this.fruits;`(or directly access `fruits[]` instead of assigning to `e`).

This will ensure the expected object state is being used in the `first` method.

Comment: @Evelyne, Good to know. All the best.